# ¿Hacer un buscador por palabras clave con mySql? necesito hacer el query de la consulta

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, buscador, sql

necesito hacer un buscador que busque por palabras clave en mi base de datos tengo un campo de palabras donde guardo todas las palabras clave que quiero para el producto.

Por ejemplo tengo un producto con palabras clave 'camisa rojo', necesito que el usuario pueda poner en el buscador esas palabras así o al revés osea 'rojo camisa' y busque todos los que coincidan con esos dos específicamente.

La verdad es que no tengo ni idea de como hacer la consulta, por eso no pongo ninguna sentencia, estoy usando mysql. Si pueden ayudarme a hacer la consulta o a ver como estructurar la base de datos para hacer esa consulta se los agradereceria :D

**Edit**
Esta es la estructura de la tabla, en el campo marcado con rojo es donde guardare las palabras clave y con eso quiero hacer la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Daniel Pat, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Gracias lo vere

Comment: Hola, no se ve muy complicado, ¿podrías al menos poner un diagrama de tu bd para entender mejor la pregunta?

Comment: Ya la agregue, espero que pueda ser más claro con eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para estas cosas lo mejor es usar [Full-text search](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php), con el que ademas puedes hasta ordenar por el que mas coincidencias tenga fácilmente

Tendrás que hacer una pequeña modificación a la hora de crear la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
palabrasClave TEXT, 
FULLTEXT(palabrasClave)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Pero luego la consulta se simplifica mucho, incluido el no tener en cuenta si va con tilde o sin ella o las mayúsculas entre otras

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM productos WHERE  MATCH(palabrasClave) AGAINST ('camisa rojo' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el operador Like 
ejemplo

```
Select campo1 where campo LIKE '%Roja%'
```

aqui me busca el comentario que tenga la palabra Roja

Comment: Ya lo intente así pero si pones dos palabras ya no funciona